# Retrieving tool input with arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) returns nulls in Python Toolbox

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, python-toolbox

I have created a python toolbox arcgiscontroller.pyt:

```
class Toolbox(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.label = "ArcGisController"
    self.alias = ""
    self.tools = [AddUpdateFeatureClasses]

class AddUpdateFeatureClasses(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.label = "AddUpdateFeatureClasses"
    self.description = ""
    self.canRunInBackground = True

def getParameterInfo(self):
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Input Json", name="inJson", datatype="GPString", parameterType="Required", direction="Input")
    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Output Json",name="outJson",datatype="GPString",parameterType="Derived",direction="Output")
    params = [param0, param1]
    return params

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
  import os
  # This can be removed once the arcgiscontroller is installed into the python path
  import sys
  sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\mypythonpath")
  from {mycustompackages} import ArcGisController
  if __name__ == "__main__":
    ArcGisController.run()
  return
```

In the called code (in `ArcGisController.run()`:), I try to get the input json like this:

```
class ArcGisController(object):
    def __init__(self):
        *initialization stuff*
    def processInput(input):
        *do stuff* 

    @staticmethod             
    def run():
        # get input parameters
        inJson = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
        processInput(inJson)
        return result
```

but the arcpy.GetParameterAsText call returns `' '`.

Does anyone know what I can do to be able to retrieve the input json in the called code? The `ArcGisController.run()` code works fine when I manually create a toolbox, so I'm guessing that part is fine and the problem lies within my python tool code.

My goal is to automate the publishing of this GP tool.

Comment: What is the *exact* syntax of your call to ArcGisController.run()? Are you actually passing the parameter to it or is it being ignored in the call?

Comment: I am calling it with that exact syntax: ArcGisController.run(). 
I am not passing any parameters to it, but trying to retrieve the input given to the python tool with arcpy.GetParamaeterAsText

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Note I have edited your code slightly to make it a little shorter to read.  I removed un-called empty functions

Comment: Are you expecting `inJson = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` to receive the value in `param0 = arcpy.Parameter()`?

Comment: Yes, that is what i wanted it to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need your `ArcGisController.run()` to request the input value

```
@staticmethod             
def run(inJson):
    # get input parameters
    processInput(inJson)
    return result
```

And in your python toolbox pass the `param0` value when you call `run()`:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Input Json", name="inJson", datatype="GPString", parameterType="Required", direction="Input")
    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Output Json",name="outJson",datatype="GPString",parameterType="Derived",direction="Output")
    params = [param0, param1]
    return params

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    import os
    # This can be removed once the arcgiscontroller is installed into the python path
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\mypythonpath")
    from {mycustompackages} import ArcGisController
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        ArcGisController.run(parameters[0].valueAsText)
    return
```